# PHP preg_replace - String Begins With Forward Slash

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

Trying to use preg_replace to find strings that begin and end with a forward-slash, for example `"/Harry/"`. (has to be preg_replace)

I also need to ignore case and ensure it is an individual word. So far I have the following but I am having little luck getting it to work :(

```
$old_words[0] = '/\b\/Harry\/\b/i';

$new_words[0] = 'Wizard';

$chat = preg_replace($old_words, $new_words, $chat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should your problem really just be the word boundaries `\b`, then you could try some auxiliary assertions instead:

```
$old_words[0] = '#(?<!\w)/Harry/(?!\w)#i';
```

That basically ensures that no letters can occur before or after the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace single words, it is not necessary to use `preg_replace`. Use [str_ireplace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) (for case-insensitive replacement) instead. However, you can use other chars than `/` as delimiter for your regular expression: `#`, `~`, …